# How to enable Map Local over https with Charles Proxy?

Tags: configuration, https, proxy, mapping, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles Proxy's handy [Map Local](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-local/) tool to develop CSS documents. This way I can immediately see my edits without having to redeploy the whole thing which in the wonderful world of enterprise-level webapps saves a considerable amount of time.

I just discovered that Map Local doesn't work with the https protocol. I have no problems with http, everything works as expected.

I'm using Windows 7, and the problem is present with every browser.

What could be misconfigured?

Comment: what you mean doesn't work? I use it in both http/https without problems. explain yourself :)

Comment: Let's say I map `http://domain/file` to a local `file`. This works as expected. But `https://domain/file` wouldn't work, the original `file` would be used instead of the local one. The only difference between the two mappings is the protocol.

Comment: Have you added the same rule with HTTPS as the protocol?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ensure that the host you're trying to map is enabled under (added to) Proxy > Proxy Settings > SSL > Locations.

Answer (score 7):

Old post, @OpaCitiZen's answer is correct, however, in version v3.11.4 & v4, it's

Proxy > SSL Proxying Settings > Add (URL) and obviously make sure the checkbox for "Enable SSL Proxying" is selected